# How to find out if a Google Cloud project is dormant?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We may have created many projects but left dormant. Is it possible to find out the last activity in these projects? We figure that if there is no activity for the last few months then it would be quite safe to suspend and eventually delete these. It may be tough to define activities, but I think they could be network traffic in/out of the resources, DB query, SSH into VMs, creating and deleting of resources, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by “dormant” you mean the project is active but you are not using it. If that is so then you can go to the VM instance details where you can change the graph to find out the network packet, network bytes or any other criteria that you desire. Also from the dashboard compute engine CPU utilization can also be found out. Furthermore, [activity logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/activity-logs) can also be used to find out the API calls or other activities of a project.

That being said, if you are referring to any other state of the project other than active one according to [this article](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects#lifecyclestate), keep in mind that there is no option to check the inactive project as of now.